# Error 'ntl' is not recognized while installing netlify to my react app

Tags: reactjs, netlify

The term 'ntl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- ntl dev
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ntl:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: When you put in your terminal **$ where netlify** or **$ where ntl** what does it say ?

Comment: I installed by VScode terminal